# What is the meaning of "<>" in an equation

Tags: notation

There is an equation reads like:

$[\mathbf{A}^2]_{ij} = \sum_{k=1, \dots,n} a_{ik}a_{kj} <> 0$

I guess that the symbol $<>$ here means $\neq$ ? But I am not sure and failed to confirm the guess by Google.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation?  Can you cite your sources, please?  Is the notation not defined in that source?

Comment: In the programming language BASIC, it means not equal to. But it could mean something different based on the context of your material

Comment: Do you have a source where this appears? The only symbol that I know which fits that description is $\gtrless$.

Comment: PARI/GP uses "<>" for "not equal" as well.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised to meet this symbol, and understand it as $\not =$. But I haven't seen it in use for at least 50 years.

Comment: Thank you! It's from a reading material of a course Scientific Programming. The course is about Matlab/Python. Two comments link it to some programming languages, I think it makes sense because the course has something to do with programming. So it may be from some programming convention that means "not equal" :) Thank you for your help!